# How to delete unique constraint in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

my code

```
alter table mytable drop unique constraint uk_mytable;
```

but shows the following error...

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'unique constraint username' at line 1"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487691/dropping-unique-constraint-from-mysql-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
alter table mytable drop uk_mytable;
```