# MySQL: issue setting unique restraint on combination of rows

Tags: mysql, database, unique

I'm trying to set a unique restraint on a combination of columns rather than on a single column. I have a table, "tags":

- id (int, PK, AI, unsigned)
- tag (varchar 25)
- user_id (int, unsigned)

Following the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487691/dropping-unique-constraint-from-mysql-table), I tried to set the combo restraint via:

```
ALTER TABLE `tags` ADD UNIQUE `unique_tag_user_combo` (`tag`, `user_id`);
```

So far, so good. But when I come to test it, by seeing if it will let me insert the same tag twice but with different user IDs (it **should**), it errors:

```
INSERT INTO `tags` VALUES (NULL, 'foo', '1'), (NULL, 'foo', '2')
```

...throws...

```
Duplicate entry 'foo' for key 'name_2'
```

Remember the unique restraint is on the combo of tag + user_id, so this query, to my mind, should run fine. I could understand this error if I'd tried to insert foo/1 twice, but not foo/1 and foo/2. What am I missing?

(EDIT - also, what's that 'name_2' reference in the error message all about? I don't have a column with that name...)

Comment: Have you checked if your table is empty before inserting those values?

Comment: It is - I newly truncated it.

Comment: Maybe you also have an unique index on tag?name_2 issue..

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtb`

Comment: Damn... there's already a unique instruction on it, you were right. If you post that comment up as the answer I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also have an unique index on tag column.Use

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtb
```