# How to make a column common from unique in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have created table in there I choosed a column to be unique AND now I want that column to be common not unique in phpmyadmin. I could not found any option like that. How can i do that ?

Can anyone tell me how to do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropping Unique constraint from MySQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487691/dropping-unique-constraint-from-mysql-table)

Comment: And the problem is..? You need to drop the index and create whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this on the w3c tutorial website:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
DROP INDEX UC_Person;
```

I tried on a table with unique contraint. It worked for the email column but not the username column. Here's the link. 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

Good luck hope it is what you need.