# Inserting UTF8 Names to Table gives a Duplicate Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, character-encoding

I have the following array with two names:

```
$x = ['Rodriguez', 'Rodríguez'];
```

Right now, What I'm trying to do is to insert these values to my Table, Which is like the following

```
Collation: utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
Engine: InnoDB
[id(primary_ai)  -  name(unique)]
```

And I do connect to the database using:

```
<?php 
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8mb4;", 'root', 'root', [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
    ]);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

And I try to insert using like this

```
$paras = $x
$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES (?), (?)")->execute($paras);
```

But I keep getting the error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Rodríguez' for key 'name'
```

How can I deal with this encoding problem exactly?

I've tried using `utf8_encode()` but the second Name changed to `RodrÃ­guez`, Then tried `utf8_decode()` but got `Rodr�guez`, Then tried adding `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"` but didn't solve the duplicate error either.

Comment: Encode/decode functions are likely to make things worse, as you see.  The two names _are_ spelled differently; one has a plain letter `i`, the other has an accute i (`í`).  But the Collation says that both i's are treated equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL takes Rodriguez and Rodríguez the same thing, you have to change your collation.

You can fix collation by using:

```
CREATE TABLE Table (...) COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Comment: What is the advantages and disadvantages of using `utf8_bin` or `utf8mb4_bin` over `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`,

Comment: That will lead to even capitalization making a difference.  Hope that is OK.

Comment: @RickJames Does that mean that it is better to use `utf8mb4_bin collation` on columns require accuracy like `username`, `private keys`, or in some cases `email`, Yet `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` is better for columns that would be searched using `LIKE` or `WHERE` to ease the use to the `user` because of its `case insensitivity`?

Comment: Collations are _aimed_ at flowing text.  For user names do you want `abc` and `Abc` to be the same or different?  You probably do want passwords to be fully sensitive, hence `utf8mb4_bin` or even `BINARY`.  Isn't email case insensitive?  But that about accents?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the unique limit from your DB or else have some other encoding that recognizes the difference between i and í.

This might work https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Comment: How exactly do I remove the unique limit of the DB?

Comment: Depends what you're using I use phpmyadmin so it's pretty easy or theres this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487691/dropping-unique-constraint-from-mysql-table